# how to locate value in object by string to translate elements on page

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object lets say it looks like this.

```json
{
    "exportRoot" : {
        "translate" : {
            "navbar" : {
                "navbarLink1" : "Start",
                "navbarLink2" : "Energy",
                "navbarLink3" : "Warmth",
                "navbarLink4" : "Water",
                "navbarLink5" : "Config"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and I have a set of elements with a class of `lang_text`, which will iterate over in a function. I check the id of the element I'm currently looking at. This will always look like this `translate.navbar.navbarLink1`. Now I want, to say, `element.innerHTML = exportRoot.id`. This doesn't seem to work and I think it may have to do with the fact that id in this case is a string.

```js
let ele = document.getElementsByClassName('lang_text');

    for (let i = 0; i < ele.length; i++ ) {
        let currentName = ele[i].id;

        // ele[i].innerHTML = exportRoot[currentName];
        ele[i].innerHTML = exportRoot.currentName;
    }
```

Anyone know how I could best go about matching my elements with the correct keys in my object?

Comment: `ele[i].innerHTML = exportRoot.translate.navbar.currentName` ?

Comment: You could split the id on the dots and use index notation to drill into exportRoot. You might also consider using a framework built for localization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is simple example of something as you described.

in `translate()` function I'm looking for every element that has `translate-key` attribute set and I'm iterating over them.

In loop I'm reading this attribute content and split it into array of next keys and provide them to `searchTranslations()` function.

In `searchTranslations()` function I'm checking if key is an object and if it is I'm calling this function again but this time on this object with one less key to find.
If item is not an object I'm returning it assuming it is string that I need.

```js
const translationTable = {
    translate: {
        navbar: {
            navbarLink1: "Start",
            navbarLink2: "Energy",
            navbarLink3: "Warmth",
            navbarLink4: "Water",
            navbarLink5: "Config"
        }
    }
}

const searchTranslations = (translationTable, translationKeyArray) => {
    const index = translationKeyArray[0];

    if (typeof(translationTable[index]) === 'object') {
        translationKeyArray.shift();
        return searchTranslations(translationTable[index], translationKeyArray);
    }

    return translationTable[index];
};

const translate = () => {
    document.querySelectorAll('[translate-key]').forEach(element => {
        const translateKeyArray = element.getAttribute('translate-key').split('.');
        element.innerText = searchTranslations(translationTable, translateKeyArray);
    });
};

translate();
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#" translate-key="translate.navbar.navbarLink1"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" translate-key="translate.navbar.navbarLink2"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" translate-key="translate.navbar.navbarLink3"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" translate-key="translate.navbar.navbarLink4"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" translate-key="translate.navbar.navbarLink5"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: This works wonderfully thank you very much! Took me a while to figure out how it actually found a match but index doesnt have to be a number